# How can I prevent background jobs from reading input from terminal?

Tags: unix, process, background, controls, jobs

I'm writing a shell program for a class and I'm having an issue I'm not completely understanding.

I have to implement background jobs.
The issues preventing the background job from reading from the terminal.
Every resource I've says to just not call wait() but that's causing an error for me.
Right now I have a small program that simply reads input and reprints it until eof.
What happens is after I fork and exec at some point while typing in other commands it starts printing 0's

0
0
0
.
.
.

I have come across some suggested solutions such as changing the process group
[UNIX System call to register a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510370/unix-system-call-to-register-a-background-process)

This solution has not stopped the problem I'm having.  From my understanding this program should be getting SIGTTIN and stopping (it's possible I've misunderstood this). Unfortunately searching anything on background process brings up mostly pages concerned with shell scripts and not implementation.

I started to write a signal handler to catch SIGTTIN however I'm not sure what to do at that point. I thought I'd use kill() to suspend the program but then how do I get the pid of the process trying to read.

edit: i should mention this issue is cause because my test program reads input in as int. But i need it to block when it reads.

edit: My simple test program is

```
  cin >> temp;
  do{
    cout << temp << endl;
    cin >> temp;

  }while(!cin.eof());
```

when it forks the child runs

```
  if(PID == 0){
    /*code for checking if IO is redirected*/
    execvpe(args[0], args, curState.getEnv());
    cout << args[0] << " not a command" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
```

The parent then checks if it should wait

```
if(jobWait()){
    waitpid(PID, &status, 0);
  }
```

Comment: which language are you using? can you post a simple example of the code you're using and how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: It's in C++ and i'll update my post with some sample code.

Comment: calling setpgid() before exec actually stops this issue however then there is an issue when trying to bring it to the foreground/resume it

Comment: it's possible i'm going about this wrong, what i need to do is implement $<command>& and fg <spid>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my issue, if I use setpgid(int, int) correctly then the background application stops when attempting to read input. I can then give it control of the terminal from the parent process with tcsetpgrp(int, int) and wait on the child with waitpid(int, &int, int), and as long as I handle SIGCHLD so the parent doesn't stop after the child exits and the Parent can then resume control with tcsetpgrp(int, int)