# C++, linux, fork, execvp, waitpid and SIGTSP

Tags: c++, linux, signals, fork, execvp

I'm implementing a Terminal for a Home Work.
I almost finished, I just need to implement a bg ( Background ) and a fg ( Foreground ) commands.
my code looks like this:

```
void run(){

    string command[] = parseMyInput( getInput() );  
    int fork_result = fork();
    if( -1 == fork_result )
        //handle error
    else if( 0 == fork_result ){  // child

         setpgrp();  // I don't want the children to get the signals

         if( -1 == execvp( command[0], makeArgs(command) ) )
             //handle error
    }
    else {  // parent

        if( command[ length - 1 ] != "&" ){

            int status;
            waitpid( fork_result, &status, 0 );

            //continue after child is finished
           //( need to be here also after a SIGTSTP is raised by ctrl+z )
        }
    }
```

If it is a foreground process ( if there wasn't a '&' sign at the end ) then I need to be able to stop the foreground process ( the child ) with ctrl+z ( SIGTSTP ) and then to return the control to the father ( my terminal ) from the point it stopped ( waitpid ).

the problem is that after a ctrl+z is pressed, ( and after the parent get the control in the signal handle method and stop the child using kill( child_pid, SIGTSTP ) ) the parent don't continue from where it stopped ( the waitpid ). I don't know where it continue after the signal handling method is finished.

If I call run() at the signal handling method it will work, but I don't want the recursion. I'm guessing I'll get a StackOverFlow very soon...

here is the code of the Signal Handling Method:

```
void sigtstp_handel( int signal ){  

    if( is_foreground_process_alive() )
        kill( foreground_process_pid, SIGTSTP );

    // run();
}
```

EDIT: I don't know if it will matter, but I'm using a Linux Ubuntu 12.10. nevertheless, for the Home Work, I'll need it to work on other systems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the official POSIX reference for [`waitpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html):

> WUNTRACED
>
> ```
> The status of any child processes specified by pid that are stopped,
> and whose status has not yet been reported since they stopped, shall
> also be reported to the requesting process.
> ```

So if you add the `WUNTRACED` flag the `waitpid` call should return when the process it waits for is stopped.